# Change array element (e.g. 4-10) into pipe separated list (e.g. 4|5|6|7|8|9|10)

Tags: php, arrays, csv, integer, element

I have tried for the last two days now searching on google and in all the forums,  but can't seem to find any answer that remotely helps me with this problem .

I have a stock feed `.csv` file which I need to change the values of the shoe sizes to work with Woocommerce. The shoe sizes are different on each row.

The sizes in the csv are listed like this: `4-10, 5-12, 3-9` etc. one set of numbers per row `4-10`. I have inputed the file into an array in my php script.

So for each shoe I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4578
    [1] => kors
    [2] => red
    [3] => wedge
    [4] => 4-10
)
```

I need to take the last value e.g. `4-10` and change them to something like this: `4|5|6|7|8|9|10`.

So basically I need to take the first number in the element and increment it by 1 and separate it with the pipe character " | "until it reaches the value of the last number. Then I need it to replace the `4-10` in the element with the `4|5|6|7|8|9|10`.

Comment: So basically you already have the above array, right? And you just want to change the last element as you described it?

Comment: What do you have so far, where are you stuck?

Comment: how do i add code into a comment on here ? sorry

Comment: Rizer123 Yeah I have got the file uploaded and converted to an array but i have no idea how to convert the last element how i described

Comment: @Biwwabong Don't add code into comments! [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29870162/edit) your question!

Comment: @Biwwabong FYI: You can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see a bit how this site works and where everything is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I first get the last element of the array and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it with `-` as delimiter. After this I simply create an array with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) where I use the `$start` and `$end` variable. At the end I simply save the element back by [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)'ing it.)

```
<?php

    $arr = [4578, "kors", "red", "wedge", "4-10"];

    list($start, $end) = explode("-", $arr[count($arr)-1]);
    $arr[count($arr)-1] = implode("|", range($start, $end));

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => 4578 [1] => kors [2] => red [3] => wedge [4] => 4|5|6|7|8|9|10 )
```